# Why does this Zend_Form NotEmpty validator give me an error message?

Tags: zend-form

For Zend Form Elements which are required I normally do this:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'loginEmail');
$this->loginEmail
        ->setLabel('Email')
        ->setRequired(true);
```

I was unhappy with the error message though.  The Zend Documentation says that `setRequired()` merely adds a NotEmpty validator to the chain, so I did this:

```
    $validator = new Zend_Validate_NotEmpty();
    $validator->setMessage('A value is required');

    $this->addElement('text', 'loginEmail');
    $this->loginEmail
            ->setLabel('Email')                
            ->addValidator($validator);
```

But now I'm not getting any error message for that element!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I didn't really get an answer to my question, however I have come to realise that the `setRequired()` validator is a complex little animal, and probably not the Zend team's proudest moment.  So, instead of looking for an answer to the question above I have found an approach to setRequired which works quite nicely.  Here it is:

```
    $this->addElement('text', 'orgName');
    $this->orgName
            ->setLabel('Name')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')                
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty', true, array(
                'messages' => 'Name is required'))                
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addValidator('Alnum', false, array(
                'allowWhiteSpace'   => true,
                'messages'          => 'Alpha and numeric characters only'))
            ->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(
                'min'       => 3,
                'max'       => 128,
                'messages'  => 'Between 3 and 128 characters'));
```

The key thing is to add the NotEmpty validator and configure it **before calling setRequired.**  When setRequired is called it detects that a NotEmpty validator has already been added to the chain and therefore does not add its own instance.